# unnecessary rerendering of flatlist

Tags: react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist

When passing the data array to the quizlist it causes the quiz to automatically rerender for.each item within the data array. quizdescription in this case has an length of 3 for context. when trying to pass a single length object through to the data array it causes me to lose the access to the specific item.id for me to navigate to the learnquiz page with the belonging questions. i am so confused and have tried for hours to figure this thing out. (worth noting that im an inexperienced programmer)

```
export const QuizPage = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { selectedQuestions, setSelectedQuestions } = useContext(SelectedQContext);

    const data = quizDescription

    const handleItemPress = (item) => {
        let newSelectedQuestions = [];

        if (item.id === 1) {
            newSelectedQuestions = questionsAvtl;
            console.log(item);
        } else if (item.id === 2) {
            newSelectedQuestions = questionsEuFEU;
        } else if (item.id === 3) {
            // Set questions for item 3
        }

        setSelectedQuestions(newSelectedQuestions);

        navigation.navigate("LearnQuiz", { itemId: item.name, questions: newSelectedQuestions });
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Searchbar />
            </View>
            <QuizList
                data={data}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Pressable onPress={() => handleItemPress(item)}>
                        <QuizPageLogic selectedQuestions={selectedQuestions} />
                    </Pressable>

                )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

tried changing the data passed to the flatlist (quizlist) to something with a length of one to try and stop the rerendering. every quiz just became the same one.